# Decoding big base64 encoded blobs

Tags: oracle, plsql, base64

I have an xml file which is about 3.5mb in size. I'm encdoing it and propagating to another database where i need to decode it. I'm decoding it in iterations since it's too big to decode in one go, however in some iterations it fails to decode, i get some giberish. I believe it's because some symbols can be 1 byte and others 2 byte's, and sometimes substring cuts one symbol of 2 byte's in half and that iteration would come up in giberish. I've figured that i can try to convert every substring to clob, since it has warnings when it fails to convert, characters and if warning comes up to, increase amount in substring by some number, byt i've yet to succeed decoding this way. Is there any workaround for this?

**UPDATE**

Succeeded in decoding, with warnings checks. All you need to do is try to convert substring to clob with `dbms_lob.convertblobtoclob` check for `warning != 0` and if so reduce offset by 1 and go to next iteration, without writing substring to your blob.  However this is very memmory costy check, because it requires to create blob and to transform that blob to a clob. Is there any simplier workaround to this, maybe i'am missing something very obvious?

**UPDATE**

I've an xml file which contains payment xml encoded in base64, and other data about that xml. f.e.

```
<envelope>
  <file_name>a.xml</file_name>
  <...><...>
  <data>BASE64 ENCODED XML FILE</data>
</envelope>
```

Complete script with few examples. Earlier i've mentioned workaround with warning checking, but in this example it seems to not work, and when i better think about it, it shouldn't. Anyway, here's script:

```
declare
  l_clob clob := empty_clob();

  function convert_clob_to_blob(
    p_clob in clob) return blob is

    l_dest_offsset number := 1;
    l_src_offsset number := 1;
    l_lang_context number := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
    l_warning number;

    l_result blob;
  begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_result, false);
    dbms_lob.convertToBlob(
      dest_lob => l_result,
      src_clob => p_clob,
      amount => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize,
      dest_offset => l_dest_offsset,
      src_offset => l_src_offsset,
      blob_csid => dbms_lob.default_csid,
      lang_context => l_lang_context,
      warning => l_warning);

    if l_warning != 0 then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'sd' || '.convert_blob_to_clob ' || l_warning);
    end if;
    return l_result;
  end;

  function gen_rand_xml return clob is

    l_xml xmltype := xmltype('<envelope><nullnode></nullnode></envelope>');
  begin
    for i in 1..50 loop
        SELECT
          insertXMLafter(
            l_xml,
            '/envelope/nullnode',
            XMLType('<node>' || i || '</node>'))
        INTO
          l_xml
        FROM dual;
    end loop;

    return l_xml.getClobVal();
  end;

  function to_base64(
    p_clob in clob) return clob is

    l_length integer;
    l_offset integer := 1;
    l_amt binary_integer := 600;
    l_buffer varchar2(1800);

    l_result clob := empty_clob();
    l_temp_blob blob;
  begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_temp_blob, false);
    l_temp_blob := convert_clob_to_blob(p_clob);

    l_length := dbms_lob.getlength(l_temp_blob);
    while l_offset < l_length loop
      l_result := l_result || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(dbms_lob.substr(l_temp_blob, l_amt, l_offset)));
      l_offset := l_offset + l_amt;
    end loop;

    return l_result;
  end;

  function from_base64(
    p_clob in clob) return clob is

    l_length integer := dbms_lob.getLength(p_clob);
    l_offset integer := 1;
    l_amt binary_integer := 800;
    l_buffer varchar2(3200);

    l_result clob := empty_clob();
  begin  

    while l_offset <= l_length loop
      l_buffer := replace(replace(dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_amt, l_offset), chr(10), null), chr(13), null);
      l_offset := l_offset + l_amt;
      while l_offset <= l_length and mod(dbms_lob.getLength(l_buffer), 4) > 0 loop
        l_buffer := l_buffer || replace(replace(dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, 1, l_offset), chr(10), null), chr(13), null);
        l_offset := l_offset + 1;
      end loop;
      l_result := l_result || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_buffer)));
    end loop;

    return l_result;
  end;

  procedure print_clob( p_clob in clob )
  as
    l_offset number default 1;
  begin
    loop
    exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
    dbms_output.put_line( dbms_lob.substr( p_clob, 4000, l_offset ) );
    l_offset := l_offset + 4000;
    end loop;
  end;
begin
  l_clob := gen_rand_xml;
  print_clob(from_base64(to_base64(l_clob)));
end;
/
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Why do you try to convert a BLOB to CLOB? For an XML file it should be fine to work all in `CLOB` (unless the XML is UTF-8 but your database works on a "lower" character set, e.g. `WE8ISO8859P1` - but then you could still use `NCLOB` )

Comment: When you use `base64_encode`, then the amount of data must be a whole multiple of 3, i.e. `l_amt binary_integer := 1000;` does not work, use `l_amt binary_integer := 999;` for example.

Comment: Changed the amount in script. And for the xml with 75 nodes it worked, however when i increased the amount of nodes to 100 it failed again.

Comment: It was more difficult than I expected. Actually you have to use `CONVERTTOBLOB` because BASE64 takes 3 **Bytes** (not characters) and convert this to 4 Bytes. Another challenge was the NEW_LINE characters you may have in BASE64 string which must  be ignored for decoding. Please have a look at updated answer, for me it works even with strings like `XMLTYPE('<ñödê>' || i || '</ñödê>')`

Comment: Yes, the NL and CR characters was the problem when decoding. And when encoding trick was to convert clob to blob before encoding. However you do not need to convert to blob when decoding. I've updated script which works for me with my payment xml.

Comment: You have to convert to BLOB when decoding if your input string contains special characters (i.e. Non-ASCII like `ñödê`). Otherwise I get back a mess.

Comment: For me it seems that it converted those characters correctly, will double check that tomorow.

Comment: Most likely that happens only with UTF-8 / UTF-16 character sets. Make buffer smaller (e.g. `l_amt binary_integer := 36;`) then you should see it.

Comment: Checked that, and symbols like "ąčė..." is decoded correctly.

Comment: Try combinations of `ąčė` and `€` currency symbol. In UTF-8 `€` is encoded by 3 bytes (xE2 x82 xAC), the other ones are encoded by 2 bytes each. For `ąč€ė` I get BASE64 string `xIXEjeKCrMSX` which is decoded back to `ąč�ė` (using `l_amt := 8;`)

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Interesting thing is that you must write decoded substrings to blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't get your point and most I don't understand why do you convert from BLOB to CLOB.

Anyway, I have a similar situation in my application, with BASE64 encoded XML inside a XML file.

For encoding and decoding I use these functions, maybe it helps in your situation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DecodeBASE64(InBase64Char IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS

    blob_loc BLOB;
    clob_trim CLOB;
    res CLOB;

    lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
    dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
    src_offset INTEGER := 1;
    read_offset INTEGER := 1;
    warning INTEGER;
    ClobLen INTEGER;

    amount INTEGER := 1440; -- must be a whole multiple of 4
    buffer RAW(1440);
    stringBuffer VARCHAR2(1440);

BEGIN

    -- Remove all NEW_LINE from base64 string
    ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(InBase64Char);
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(clob_trim, TRUE);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN read_offset > ClobLen;
        stringBuffer := REPLACE(REPLACE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(InBase64Char, amount, read_offset), CHR(13), NULL), CHR(10), NULL);
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(clob_trim, LENGTH(stringBuffer), stringBuffer);
        read_offset := read_offset + amount;
    END LOOP;

    read_offset := 1;
    ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(clob_trim);
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(blob_loc, TRUE);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN read_offset > ClobLen;
        buffer := UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clob_trim, amount, read_offset)));
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(blob_loc, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(buffer), buffer);
        read_offset := read_offset + amount;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(res, TRUE);
    DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOCLOB(res, blob_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, dest_offset, src_offset,  DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_context, warning);

    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(blob_loc);
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(clob_trim);
    RETURN res;


END DecodeBASE64;




CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EncodeBASE64(InClearChar IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS

    dest_lob BLOB;  
    lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
    dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
    src_offset INTEGER := 1;
    read_offset INTEGER := 1;
    warning INTEGER;

    amount INTEGER := 1440; -- must be a whole multiple of 3
    buffer RAW(1440);
    res CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();

BEGIN

    IF DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(InClearChar) IS NULL THEN 
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(dest_lob, TRUE);
    DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB(dest_lob, InClearChar, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, dest_offset, src_offset, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_context, warning);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN read_offset >= dest_offset;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(dest_lob, amount, read_offset, buffer);
        res := res || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(buffer));       
        read_offset := read_offset + amount;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(dest_lob);
    RETURN res;


END EncodeBASE64;
```

You can use it like this

```
DECLARE
    str VARCHAR2(1000) := '<envelope><file_name>a.xml</file_name><data>some text</data></envelope>';
    base64 VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    base64 := EncodeBASE64(str);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( base64 );

    str :=  DecodeBASE64(base64);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( str );

END;
```

Output:

```
PGVudmVsb3BlPjxmaWxlX25hbWU+YS54bWw8L2ZpbGVfbmFtZT48ZGF0YT5zb21l
IHRleHQ8L2RhdGE+PC9lbnZlbG9wZT4=
<envelope><file_name>a.xml</file_name><data>some text</data></envelope>
```

Perhaps this example is closer to your use case:

```
DECLARE
    payment CLOB := '<payment><amout>50 Cent</amout><recipient>Wernfried Domscheit</recipient></payment>';
    envelope XMLTYPE;
    base64 CLOB;

BEGIN

    SELECT 
        XMLELEMENT("envelope", 
            XMLELEMENT("file_name", 'a.xml'),
            XMLELEMENT("data", EncodeBASE64(payment))
        )
    INTO envelope
    FROM dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( envelope.getclobval() || CHR(13));

    SELECT RETURN_BASE64
    INTO base64
    FROM XMLTABLE('envelope/data' PASSING envelope COLUMNS
        RETURN_BASE64 CLOB PATH '/');       
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( base64 || CHR(13) );

    payment := DecodeBASE64(base64);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( payment );

END;
```

Output:

```
<envelope><file_name>a.xml</file_name><data>PHBheW1lbnQ+PGFtb3V0PjUwIENlbnQ8L2Ftb3V0PjxyZWNpcGllbnQ+V2VybmZy
aWVkIERvbXNjaGVpdDwvcmVjaXBpZW50PjwvcGF5bWVudD4=</data></envelope>

PHBheW1lbnQ+PGFtb3V0PjUwIENlbnQ8L2Ftb3V0PjxyZWNpcGllbnQ+V2VybmZy
aWVkIERvbXNjaGVpdDwvcmVjaXBpZW50PjwvcGF5bWVudD4=

<payment><amout>50 Cent</amout><recipient>Wernfried Domscheit</recipient></payment>
```

In order not to waste memory you should always use `IN OUT NOCOPY` clause when you work with LOB's. By this the LOB is not copied for procedure call, you just pass a pointer.

Comment: Since you mentioned that i don't need to convert it to blob and then again to clob, i've corrected my functions according to your example. I've updated the script. Added random xml generator to script, so you could see what i'm facing. However, issue remains the same. When decoding from base64, parts of my xml fails to decode.